# How to make the AngularJS to switch between views and show updated list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie.
Below is my html & js code. When I click on "Add" friend,

1. $scope.friends list not getting updated. I am getting undefined for $scope.newFriend.name, $scope.newFriend.age etc..
2. Also how to reload view1 to show the updated list.

**----- main.html -----**

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<body>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="FriendsController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <p>I'am {{name}} have {{friends.length}} friends. </br>They are:</p>
  <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Find by name/age/gender" /> | <a href="#/add">Add Friend</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js">      </script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script>
 var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

 demoApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'FriendsController'
  }).
   when('/add', {
    templateUrl: 'view2.html',
    controller: 'FriendsController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);

 demoApp.controller('FriendsController', function($scope){
$scope.name = "Joeey";
$scope.newFriend = {};
    $scope.friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy', sal :100},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Pabtrgick1', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Pabtrgick2', age:40, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
];

$scope.addFriend = function(){
  $scope.friends.push({
    name : $scope.newFriend.name,
    age : $scope.newFriend.age,
    gender : $scope.newFriend.gender
  })
  console.log($scope.friends);
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**---- view1.html ---**

```
<ul>
<li  ng-repeat="f in friends  | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
  [{{$index + 1}}] {{f.name | lowercase}} - {{f.gender | uppercase}} is {{f.age}} years old & salary is {{f.sal}}.
</li>
</ul>
```

**---- view2.html ---**

```
<br/>Name: <input type="text" ng-bind="newFriend.name" />
<br/>Age: <input type="text" ng-bind="newFriend.age" />
<br/>Gender: <input type="text" ng-bind="newFriend.gender" />
<br/><button ng-click="addFriend()">Add</button>
```

**---- EDIT (Added factory method & modified FriendsController) ---**

```
demoApp.factory('friendsFactory', function(){
 var friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy', sal :100},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Pabtrgick1', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Pabtrgick2', age:40, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
];
var factory = {};
factory.getFriends = function(){ return friends};

return factory;
 });


demoApp.controller('FriendsController', function($scope, $location, friendsFactory){
$scope.name = "Joeey";
    $scope.friends = friendsFactory.getFriends();

$scope.addFriend = function(){
  $scope.friends.push({
    name : $scope.newFriend.name,
    age : $scope.newFriend.age,
    gender : $scope.newFriend.gender
  })
  $location.url('/')
}
});
```

Comment: I think your two views are getting different instances of the controller.  If you want to share the data, you have to store it in a service.  Also, for two way binding, use ng-model not ng-bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1). You really should separate concerns. Listing friends and adding a new one - should be better handled by two different controllers: `FriendsController` and `NewFriendController`.

2). Sharing friends array in this case would be ideal with a custom service, say `Friends`.

3). Instead of `ng-bind` you want to use `ng-model` to be able to pass form data back to controller.

4). And finally to redirect to another route use `$location` service: `$locations.route('/')`.

It could look like this:

```
demoApp.factory('Friends', function() {
    var friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 25,
        gender: 'boy',
        sal: 100
    }];
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            return friends;
        },
        addNew: function(friend) {
            friends.push(friend);
            return this.getAll();
        }
    };
});

demoApp.controller('FriendsController', function($scope, Friends) {
    $scope.name = "Joeey";
    $scope.friends = Friends.getAll();
});

demoApp.controller('NewFriendController', function($scope, Friends, $location) {
    $scope.addFriend = function() {
        Friends.addNew($scope.newFriend);
        $location.path('/');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1fPCavXuqhkyH2lrue2c?p=preview

Now when you have a `Friends` service it will be easy to extend functionality and use remote database, REST api, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have two views getting different instances of the controller. If you want to share the data, you have to store it in a service or take the controller declarations off of your views and just leave the top-level ng-controller (next to the ng-app attribute).

Also, for two way binding, use ng-model not ng-bind, the latter is only for model -> view updates, not useful for input elements.

Check this out...

Notice how the first two fields stay in sync because they are sharing a controller, but the last field gets its own instance of the controller and therefore doesn't sync with the others.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LCPM8hCp43093Hu64Igt

As others said, finally, inject $location and use $location.path('/') in addFriend() to return to view1.

Answer (score 1):

You mistakes just a typos, check the [Angular Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/)

1. To bind input values to angular `$scope` variables you need to use `ng-model` attribute instead of `ng-bind`. `ng-bind` is used only for printing values, `ng-model` does exactly that you want.
2. To load `view1` after adding friend you can call `$location.url('/')` in you `$scope.addFriend` method. Don't forget inject `$location` in your controller

Comment: just-boris & Craig Squire,

Thanks for pointing it out, I changed ng-bind to model, added location  and added factory method to store the data. As Craig pointed out, the views are getting different instances of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you change scope's value, you need to $apply changes.

```
$scope.addFriend = function(){
  $scope.$apply(function() { 
        $scope.friends.push({
              name : $scope.newFriend.name,
              age : $scope.newFriend.age,
              gender : $scope.newFriend.gender
        });
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. adding apply as you said, errored out with "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress ". I guess apply is not the right solution here. I added factory method to store data. it worked now. I have updated my question with the solution.

Comment: Functions executed from ng-click are already executed in a digest cycle, calling $apply() is not needed.